# The method '[]' was called on null, but it's not null

Tags: flutter, flutter-future

That title error is pointed on this line:

```
Text('${intData['summary']['intrested']}')
```

I want to display here data from backend, but I don't know how to accomplish that I am getting this error, but this is not null.

Here is my code:

```
var intData;

Future<Map> loadMyFriends(String eventId) async {
    
    var request = await EndPoints.interest(eventId, userId);
    print(request.body);
    intData = jsonDecode(request.body)['data'] as Map;
    return jsonDecode(request.body)['data'];
  }


@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    userId = widget.userId;
    loadMyFriends(widget.partyMap['id']).then((value) => print('$intData'));
  }

@override
  void didUpdateWidget(SquareBoxMovableBuilder oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    if (widget.partyMap != oldWidget.partyMap) {
      loadMyFriends(widget.partyMap['id']);
      print(intData);
    }
  }
```

and here are console prints what intData contains:

```
//print(request.body) in loadMyFriends function
{"data":{"intrested":null,"participate":null,"summary":{"intrested":0,"participate":0},"friends":{"list":[],"sum":0}}}

//print(intData) in initState
{intrested: null, participate: null, summary: {intrested: 0, participate: 0}, friends: {list: [], sum: 0}}

//print(intData) in didUpdateWidget
{intrested: null, participate: null, summary: {intrested: 0, participate: 0}, friends: {list: [], sum: 0}}
```

I tried to do this with FutureBuilder but I had same result.
How to fix it or how to do it?
How to display data downloaded from backend every time when I open this widget?

Comment: `print(initData)` inside `build` method, what do you see?

Comment: @pskink it's null

Comment: that's why you have that error, what you really need is `FutureBuilder` - first check the official docs for that class - they have some sample code

Comment: I had same error with FutureBuilder, I tried it

Comment: most likely you didn't follow the sample code from the official docs

Comment: more here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Answer (score 0):

While the `loadMyFriends` is a future method and it will take some time to get data and after getting data you need to call `setState((){})` to update the UI. You can try on

```dart
Future<Map> loadMyFriends(String eventId) async {
    
    var request = await EndPoints.interest(eventId, userId);
    print(request.body);
    intData = jsonDecode(request.body)['data'] as Map;
    setState((){}); //here
    return jsonDecode(request.body)['data'];
  }
```

Comment: It's launching now, but error screen its still showing, for 1 second, maybe less, but it's showing.

Comment: It's showing and it's dissappear immediately

Comment: Can you remove from `didUpdateWidget` for now.

Comment: It's happening only on initState actually

Comment: try to create another x method  and place it inside initState, then put `loadMyFriends` inside x method. also you need to make x method as async. If it fails can you include full widget of [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), initState cant be async